# SOAP Web Service Method for two top level nodes

Tags: soap, apex-webservice

I have a client who needs a web service method for a 3rd party to send a SOAP call to. But this soap call has two top level nodes in the body.

```
<body>
    <blockOne> 
        <data> blahblahblah </data>
        <moreData> blahblahblah </moreData>
    </blockOne>
    <blackTwo> 
        <evenMoreData> blahblahblah </evenMoreData>
    </blockTwo>
</body>
```

Is this even possible within Salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by using the [`webservice`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services_methods.htm) keyword from Apex. Those are limited to a single return type. The closest you'd probably get is returning a List of something.

You could look at mimicking a SOAP request and response pattern using [REST Web Services](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest.htm). These would be annotated for `@HttpPost` and could expose the [`RestResponse.responseBody`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm) as required.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Do you know of any other documentation on the REST setup? I have gotten a @HttpGet call working just fine, but am stumbling on the Post. This is what I have been using as reference (https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html)

I don't know if I am failing on the apex class, the request URL, request body, or all of the above